# Databind two or more entities to a single DataSource (EF6)

Tags: c#, datagridview, frameworks, entity

Well, I'm trying to databind my model to the dataGridView's datasource, but I have a problem, a little-big one.
for this example, let's use this model:

```
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Clients
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display on dataGridView's DataSource the following columns: OrderID, Total and the Name of the Client.
My GetOrders() returns a IList and I can get the name through code.

```
IList<Orders> orders = GetOrders();
var name = orders.Clients.Name;
```

Should I use IEnumerable? IQueryable? IList? I don't know what to do anymore. 
Should I create a View?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know just what type of collection to use? And what is the reason for that? Performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create property in Orders class, like this:

```
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }

    public string ClientsName
    {
      if(Clients != null)
      {
         return Clients.Name
      }

      return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

or in partial class. Next you should bind Collection of Orders to your dataGridView.